# Is there a good DNS server library in ruby?

Tags: ruby, dns

I want to create a test DNS server in ruby, but could not find anything suitable. I found pnet-dns(http://rubyforge.org/projects/pnet-dns/). This project is incomplete and buggy. Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 3):

A language-agnostic alternative is to use [PowerDNS](http://wiki.powerdns.com/trac) [pipe backend](http://doc.powerdns.com/pipebackend-dynamic-resolution.html). Because it communicates with a name server across a simple pipe, it can be written in any language, including Ruby. (The [simple example in the documentation](http://doc.powerdns.com/backends-detail.html#PIPEBACKEND) uses Perl but it should be easy to translate.)

Answer (score 3):

[RubyDNS](http://www.oriontransfer.co.nz/software/ruby-dns/index) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout an another approach of DNS server in ruby using celluloid: https://github.com/celluloid/celluloid-dns

The original `celluloid-dns` is horribly incomplete (v0.0.1). Recently, RubyDNS is being copied into `celluloid-dns` (I'm doing this as we speak). RubyDNS will be modified to work with the updated `celluloid-dns` since all core functions will be moved from RubyDNS to `celluloid-dns`.

If you want something that works right now, use RubyDNS. However, in the future, if you just want the low level APIs, use `celluloid-dns`.

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked at [Dnsruby](https://rubygems.org/gems/dnsruby)?

It aims to be fully RFC compliant, although it focuses primarily on the client side. It is, however, possible to write your own server - use `Dnsruby::Message#decode` to decode incoming packets, and a zone of RRSets holding your test records. You can then encode your packets to send back to the client.

Comment: OP asks for Ruby **server**, not client.