# Checking a URL for hostname

Tags: ruby, regex, rubygems

I am trying to evaluate user-submitted urls to find out whether they contain valid hostnames (formatting) and if so, extract the hostname. Know of any libraries/methods that could help?

Example:

```
user_input = "www.google.com"

if user_input.has_valid_host?
  hostname = user_input.get_hostname #=> "google.com"
  url = "http://" + @hostname #=> "http://google.com"
else 
  puts "Invalid URL"
end
```

This example is very simple but I need the url checked against all valid domain extensions and the hostname extracted from any string (assuming that it's present)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know ruby, but I wouldn't think of this as a ruby question.

I would use regex to split out the hostname as you suggest.

Then I would do a system call to the [nslookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nslookup) routine.

On a Windows system from the command prompt it is nslookup.

```
C:\Users\xyz>nslookup www.google.com
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.237.2

Name:    www.l.google.com
Address:  173.194.73.99
Aliases:  www.google.com.localdomain
```

From Ruby you should do an API call instead of using the command line, but both will eventually interface to the DNS service on the local machine.

See: [Is there a good DNS server library in ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/852123/is-there-a-good-dns-server-library-in-ruby)

Comment: Thanks, the `net-dns` gem would probably work if I took some time to integrate it into the small web app I'm running but I decided to 'dumb down' the question and solve the problem with something like the `addressable` gem